# D-punch/die set for SMA panel cut-out

Tags: tools

I'm looking for a D-punch/die set for SMA bulkhead cut-outs into 1mm thick plastic. Coax connector manufacturers don't seem to offer such tools (even though there are many manufacturers offering such widely used connectors)... I'm wondering if anything like this even exists ? Has anybody heard of anything that may be used for cutting out SMA coaxial holes into thin panels ?

Comment: Whether this is even possible will, very much, depend on the plastic. If it's something brittle like acrylic, it will just shatter. Many softer plastics probably won't cut cleanly.

Comment: Laser cutting may be a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm wondering if anything like this even exists ? Has anybody heard of
> anything that may be used for cutting out SMA coaxial holes into thin
> panels ?*

Try [Duratool](http://www.duratool.com/): -

[image]

Also available from [CTC](http://www.ctm-inc.com/html/panel_punch_store.html), [Greenlee](https://www.greenlee.com/br/en/punch-unit-connector-9-pin-229-229?w=2&c=161&b=86&r=30&p=1&l=4&v=c) and quite possibly several other sources.

It does look like Greenlee do these punches: -

[image]

It may be that this is the very one you seek: -

[image]

Available from [here](https://www.l-com.com/d-sub-punch-d-hole-05-diameter-greenlee-60077) with the part number being Greenlee # 60077.

Comment: I have used square Greenlee punches on metal, but never plastic. Some plastics are too brittle to be punched.

Comment: The pertinent question (that might lead to a suitable supplier) is this: *Has anybody heard of anything that may be used for cutting out SMA coaxial holes into thin panels ?* - Sure, metal punches may be problematic with some plastics but, it'll be the same guys making a plastic product who make the metal punches.

Comment: H, thanks for the suggestions. Il keep that one in mind. I should have been more specific about the "D". Its not as such for a D type connector, but more of a "D" shaped hole - round with a notch. SMA coaxial connectors have this recommended panel cut-out in the datasheets ...

Comment: Otherwise, I can confirm I'm not worried about the plastic being brittle... The material is   more of a flex-board and pliable. Can be cut by a sharp knife ... Using a punch and die would just leave cleaner edges around the cut...

Comment: Have you tried visiting the three I mention in my answer to see if they do the punch style that you need?

Comment: I had a look at Greenlee as it's one that also came to mind. SMA coaxial may not be Duratool's cup of tea though ...

Comment: As a last resort I may just have them machined from brass as most shops would find this fairly easy to do and may cost even less ...

Comment: [This kit from Greenlee](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/175/MA6558-1532308.pdf) certainly has a round D coax puncher in it. Look on pg7 (speciality knockouts). They seem to make three sizes so, contact Greenlee.

Comment: I'm  gonna take look. There's no doubt it looks like they make great tools but am worried about the cost a little ... thanks again it may be a source of inspiration ...

Comment: @citizen if we are done here then I probably don't need to remind you how to give thanks properly on stack exchange.

Comment: I've got a quick reply from Greenlee this morning. Unfortunately they don't do punch & dies that small :-( I'll look at custom machining in "cheap and cheerful" steel given the final plastic is soft to cut. Thanks for the suggestions ...

Comment: @citizen if we are done here then I probably don't need to remind you how to give thanks properly on stack exchange.